Airflow on Kubernetes with Service Account
I'm having a rough time migrating Airflow to EKS. I have an airflow instance that is deployed to eks/kubernetes. I created a service account 'airflow-pod-mgr' and bound it and all that.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: namespace
  name: airflow-pod-mgr-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    # verbs: ["list", "create", "delete"]
    verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: namespace
  name: airflow-pod-mgr
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: airflow-pod-mgr-rolebinding
  namespace: namespace
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: airflow-pod-mgr
    namespace: namespace
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: airflow-pod-mgr-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

I've set in_cluster=True in the airflow.cfg yet my DAGs just keep asking for '.kube/config' which it shouldn't since it should be defaulting to the default SA. When I exec into a worker and run a kubectl command, it's being executed by the service account, but the airflow logs are telling me this:
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"blue-analytics\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}

To me, this looks like it's using another user, so I'm just at a loss for this, I've been banging my head for a few days on these errors.

This was a great one. My dags and pods are defined in another repo with KubernetesPodOperator() and they are passing in_cluster=True which overrides what I posted above.
